# Email Obfuscation: Is antispambot() Acceptable?

Tags: filters, email, the-content, encoding

I've been looking into Email Obfuscation and trying to get away from obfuscation plugins when I ran across this code snippet[1]:

```
function remove_plaintext_email($emailAddress) {
    $emailRegEx = '/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})/i';
    return preg_replace_callback($emailRegEx, "encodeEmail", $emailAddress);
}
function encodeEmail($result) {
    return antispambot($result[1]);
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_plaintext_email', 20 );
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'remove_plaintext_email', 20 );
```

For me, this pretty much replaces any obfuscation plugin out there in a few lines of code which is always good. My concern is the way `antispambot()` tries to hide the email via converting it to HTML Entities. My question is, is that enough to stop spambots from grabbing the email? This function has been around for so long I just wanted to make sure it was still valid to use or if there was a better way to hide emails from spambots.

[1] [Source](http://www.laceytechsolutions.co.uk/wordpress-development/hide-email-addresses-from-spambots-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `antispambot()` method is still very reliable and robust from my experience, I have not had many problems using it but something else to look at depending on how far you are willing to go in securing your email address is to look into probably one of the easiest and most effective methods but also least known, believe it or not just requires minor CSS. I know MADNESS ;-)

You write your email address backwards and then reverse the text direction using CSS when its is rendered in the browser like this

> Example output in browser: mattroyal@gmail.com

HTML

```
<span class="obfuscate">moc.liamg@layorttam</span>
```

CSS

```
.obfuscate { unicode-bidi: bidi-override; direction: rtl; }
```

The other CSS trick for obfuscating is to add in some random text. Take this dummy email address for example below.

> Example output in browser: mattroyal@gmail.com

HTML

```
<span class="obfuscate">
    mattroyal<span>no</span>@<span>spammers</span>gmail<span>allowed</span>.com
</span>
```

CSS

```
.obfuscate span { display: none; }
```

Both these methods have the downside of not being able to use the `mailto:` and then of course if anyone copies the email address, when they paste it, it will be backwards or have the random text you have added to it as well.

However these methods have proven to be extremely effective and you could even combine them with encode/decoding methods as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've also posted this on [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61885/html-entities-to-hide-email-addresses) to get their opinion which varies from yours a bit (they believe HTML Entities is easily beatable at this point) but I did [read an article](http://perishablepress.com/best-method-for-email-obfuscation/) which says that you're right, the CSS method is probably the most secure / best way to prevent spambots from getting email addresses. On the otherhand though it's not very visually appealing :/

Comment: The problem with living in an imperfect world I guess is their are rarely perfect solutions anymore :-) Anyway, thanks for the feedback, I think it also depends on how visible your site is. most of my sites get a couple hundred to a couple thousand visitors a month they not all that out there so not a beaker for spambots but sites that have a wider reach would likely have more problems with this than I do because of their popularity and wider reach/higher rankings, etc...